# A question about rate of convergence of an iteration method

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

I've got these two sequences

1. $${x_n}{_+}{_1}={x_n}{_-}{_1}{x_n}^2$$
   or
2. $${x_n}{_+}{_1}={x_n}{x_n}{_-}{_1}^2$$

how can I know where do they converge to and what is the rate of convergence when they are not constant and also do converge (for sure)?

for the first one I guessed that it might converges to zero only
and the second one to zero or one but I'm not really sure about that and I don't know how to show that.

we usually use $${\epsilon_n}={x_n}-c$$

$${\epsilon_n}{_+}{_1}+c=({\epsilon_n}{_-}{_1}+c)({\epsilon_n}+c)^2$$
so if it really converges to zero then c=0 and we get

$${\epsilon_n}{_+}{_1}=({\epsilon_n}{_-}{_1})({\epsilon_n})^2$$
and then I don't know how to show what the rate is.

we usually get something like that
$${\epsilon_n}{_+}{_1}={\epsilon_n}{\epsilon_n}{_-}{_1}$$
and from that I can conclude what the order is.
any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: You're right sorry.

Comment: You get from products to sums by applying the logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the logarithm, then the second equation as the easier example becomes
$$
\ln|x_{n+1}|=\ln|x_n|+2\ln|x_{n-1}|
$$
is a linear recursion. Its characteristic polynomial $q^2=q+2$ or $0=q^2-q-2=(q-2)(q+1)$ has roots $2$ and $-1$, so that
$$
x_n=A^{2^n}\cdot B^{(-1)^n}
$$
where the constants are determined from the initial values $x_0=AB$, $x_1=A^2B^{-1}$.

With $|A|<1$ one gets convergence to zero, $|A|=1$ and $B\ne1$ a bounded but not converging sequence and for $|A|>1$ a diverging sequence.

Comment: Thank you.
actually I've got to that characteristic polynomial but the thing is I didn't really know how to get to the rate of convergence